# Change OR logic of get_adjacent_post into AND

Tags: next-post-link

```
" AND tt.term_id IN ( $term_array )"
```

get_adjacent_post uses an OR logic to find next/prev posts with identic terms of the current post, via the IN operator, and I would like to change that into an AND logic, so that all terms of the current post must match for the next/prev links. Additionally, no extra terms should be allowed.

Is there a filterable solution, does this require a change in core, and is it necessary to use query string manipulations?

How do I replace the IN operator with a sub-query that gets all object IDs that have all of the term IDs in common?

The full code for in question (with the in_same_term parameter active):

```
if ( $in_same_term ) {
            $join  .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id";
            $where .= $wpdb->prepare( 'AND tt.taxonomy = %s', $taxonomy );

            if ( ! is_object_in_taxonomy( $post->post_type, $taxonomy ) ) {
                return '';
            }
            $term_array = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

            // Remove any exclusions from the term array to include.
            $term_array = array_diff( $term_array, (array) $excluded_terms );
            $term_array = array_map( 'intval', $term_array );

            if ( ! $term_array || is_wp_error( $term_array ) ) {
                return '';
            }

            $where .= ' AND tt.term_id IN (' . implode( ',', $term_array ) . ')';
        }
```

Comment: There's no filter in there that will let you change the value. You will need to copy the function to your theme as a new function and make this change there.